# Move Notification Center to the left

Tags: macos, notifications, alert

Is there a way to move the OS X notification center, or at least the notification alerts, to the left side of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: No. The UI clearly states there is only one location:

[image]

and there appear to be no preferences one can set through the UI, or anywhere else, for that matter, to move it elsewhere.